# Deleting files in directory after one minute

Tags: php, timing

i think this question was asked few times, which I have went through and was using some of the code from the net. Right now Im encountering problem with the time.

Let me furnish the code first:

```
<?php
   $pathToDir = getcwd();               

   $pathToFilesDir = $pathToDir . '\files';

   $pathToFiles = $pathToFilesDir . '\\';

    if ($handle = opendir($pathToFilesDir)) {

        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) { 

            $filelastmodified = filemtime($file);

            if ($file != '.' && $file != '..'){               

                if((time() - $filelastmodified) > 60 && is_file($file)){

                    unlink($pathToFiles . $file);

                }                
            }                 
        }
        closedir($handle); 
    }

?>
```

This was what I was trying, to auto delete the files which are one minute older. Just for testing purposes I was trying for one minute. The result is that the files dont get deleted. On the other hand I just removed this timing condition

```
if((time() - $filelastmodified) > 60 && is_file($file))
```

and ran the script, which could delete the files immediately.

Can any one spot the mistake which I am making?

Thanks
Raaks

Comment: What is the output for $filelastmodified? and the output for time() - $filelastmodified?

Comment: hi james this is the output which you have asked filelastmodified1339080970
Current Time 1339081082
filelastmodified1336403418
Current Time 1339081082
filelastmodified1339076378
Current Time 1339081082
filelastmodified1336404883
Current Time 1339081082
filelastmodified1336404888
Current Time 1339081082

Comment: it's strange, because i'm use same code and it works, it's my check `if ((time() - @filemtime($dir.$file)) < $lifetime) {`

Comment: Raak, that number comes out to be 2677664 after subtraction. So you'd probably have to figure out what unit of measure it's using. I don't believe it's in seconds.

Comment: @James:  [The documentation](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) says that it is in seconds since 1970.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here my code check cache by lifetime, it works fine.

```
if (is_file($dir.$file) && is_readable($dir)) {
    if ($lifetime) {
        @clearstatcache();
        if ((time() - @filemtime($dir.$file)) < $lifetime) {
            return file_get_contents($dir.$file); # Return the cache
        } else {
            @unlink($dir.$file); # Cache has expired
        }
    } else {
        return file_get_contents($dir.$file); # Return the cache
    }
} return null; # Cache not found
```

Comment: Why do you expect `clearstatcache`, `filemtime` and `unlink` to fail (error supression operator)? I mean you check if the file exist, don't you? And in case permissions aren't setup well, don't you think a warning would be useful?

Comment: @hakre, a concurrent process could delete the file, so filemtime/file_get_contents/unlink will fail